# failing at downloading an image with "urllib.request.urlretrieve" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, web-crawler, ssl-certificate

If possible point the solution as well

My Code:

```
import random
import urllib.request

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,1000)
    fullname = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullname)

download_web_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg")
```

The Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
>       encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
>       self.connect()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1400, in connect
>       server_hostname=server_hostname)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
>       _context=self, _session=session)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in **init**
>       self.do_handshake()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake()
>   ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/macintosh/PycharmProjects/Claculatorer/Bucky.py", line 9, in 
>       download_web_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg")
>     File "/Users/macintosh/PycharmProjects/Claculatorer/Bucky.py", line 7, in download_web_image
>       urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullname)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
>       with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
>       return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
>       response = self._open(req, data)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
>       '_open', req)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
>       result = func(*args)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
>       context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
>       raise URLError(err)
>   urllib.error.URLError:
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: did you try using the code in my answer?

Comment: I did but it didn’t work it gives this Error nonetheless

Comment: that is odd... how are you running the code?

Comment: @MosheSlavin with PyCharm, i create a python file and hit run, I think this has something to do with the websites that are HTTPS, bc if the image is from a HTTP webpage it will be downloaded without any problem, I don’t understand why SSL ruins it

Comment: can I suggest you use request instead... that way you can add `verify=False` I'll add to my answer

Comment: @MosheSlavin I fixed the problem with: /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to use the command:

```
 /Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Comment: I think a bit of context would benefit this answer. Why does this command solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me:

```
import random
import urllib.request

def download_web_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1,1000)
    fullname = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fullname)

print(download_web_image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_100.jpg"))
```

This outputs: `None` but it's fine!

The file is saved in the same directory as the script.

[image]

Here is the way I ran the script:
[image]